# How to make multiple users login with single route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a code for login. I have 2 Schemas one is User and Admin. Right now I have two login route url `/login` for *normal users and super admin* , `adminLogin` for *admin users and also super admin* as well.

I want to combine these two schema with single route `/login` only.

Here is my code for `/login` route which  is same as `/adminLogin` Only the difference is **User** and **Admin** (Schemas) in the code

```
router.post('/login' , (req, res, next) => {

    User.find({email: req.body.email})
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
        if(user.length < 1) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                message: "Auth failed. User not found."
            })
        }
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) =>{
        if (err) {
        return res.json({
                message: "Auth failed. Check email and password"
                });             
            }


            if (result && user[0].isVerified === true){
                const adminEmail = "xyz@temp-mail.com";                                                 
                const role = user[0].email===adminEmail? "superadmin" : "user";     //---- Here in case of Admin schema -> "superadmin" : "admin";
                const token = jwt.sign( 
                    {
                        email: user[0].email,
                        userId: user[0]._id,
                        phoneNo: user[0].phoneNumber,
                        role            
                    },
                    process.env.JWT_KEY,
                    {
                        expiresIn : "1h"
                    });
                    return res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Auth Successful",
                    token : token
                    });
            }
            else{
                console.log("user is not verified");    
                return res.json({
                message: "User is not verified"
                }); 
            }
```

How can I use **Admin.find()** for Admin schema in the same login function ?

Comment: How do you distinguish an admin from a normal user? Just checking if a record exists for the email in either set?

Comment: @HenryWoody I have separate collection for that. Registration link is different for normal users and admin users.

Comment: Also maybe consider having only a single user model that has a field like userLevel or isAdmin. If you want login to be in the same place, perhaps they are similar enough to be one model.

Comment: @HenryWoody Ok , but  how can I assign isAdmin feature in model so that later it can be done from client side ?

Comment: Generally other admins would be able to promote other users to admin (`isAdmin === true`), but if you don't currently have a way for users (or at least admins) to see other users, you would have to create a way to do that. But you could also do it however you do admin creation right now, just replace the `Admin` model with the `User` model but then set `isAdmin` to `true` when creating a user account that should be an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your schema, first refactor your code like this:

```
function handle(find_func, base_role, req, res, next) {
     find_func( // your original code inside User.find, change "superadmin" : "user" to "superadmin" : base_role
     ...);
}
```

for normal user login, call

```
handle(User.find, "user", req, res, next);
```

for admin user login, call

```
handle(Admin.find, "admin", req, res, next);
```

Now you need to distinguish whether a login is from a normal user or an admin user.  Without merging your admin and user schema into one larger schema with one new field "role" indicating whether it's normal user or admin user, you can query if the username is in User collection and if not query if it is in Admin collection, then call corresponding `handle`.

Comment: No but again here there is separate url. I need only one `/login` route for both the schemas .

Comment: Where and how can I write that handle function ?

Comment: You can write it anywhere unless you import it correctly. So I suggest put that function in the same file where you write `router.post('/login',...`

Answer (score 0):

you can use query params to send type of the user and can get this params inside controller function in req.query object.